# solr indexing not working when i try to insert 1000000 rows but works fine when i try to index 400000 rows or below

Tags: solr, full-text-indexing

iam using solr 4.7.1 and trying to do a full import.My data source is a table in mysql. It has 10000000 rows and 20 columns.

Whenever iam trying to do a full import solr stops responding. But when i try to do a import of 400000 or less it works fine.

If i try to import more than this solr wont index the result it either stops responding or will show "indexing failed". In the error log it says "Unable to execute query".But i dont understand how is the query running fine for lesser number of records but fails when i run more number of records

My system config are follows

CPU-i7
Ram -6Gb
OS-64 bit windows 7
I am not able to figure out what the problem is ,i have tried increasing the max_allowed_packet to 1000M and even java heap size.

please help thanks in advance

This is the error code

`Exception while processing: playername document : SolrInputDocument(fields: []):org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT player_id,firstname,lastname,value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6, value7,value8,value9,value10, value11,value18,value19,value20, country_id, playername_modtime,player_flag from playername WHERE 'true' != 'false' OR playername.playername_modtime > '2014-05-23 10:38:56' Processing Document # 1 at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:71) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.(JdbcDataSource.java:281) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:238) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:42) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:243) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:477) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:416) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:331) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:239) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:411) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:483) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:464) Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 130,037 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 130,038 milliseconds ago. at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1127) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2288) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:2044) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3549) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:489) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3240) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2411) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2834) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2832) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2781) at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:908) at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:788) at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.(JdbcDataSource.java:274) ... 12 more Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 6 bytes, read 4 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost. at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3161) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2269) ... 23 more 5/23/2014 8:32:18 PM ERROR DataImporter Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT player_id,​firstname,​lastname,​value1,​value2,​value3,​value4,​value5,​value6,​ value7,​value8,​value9,​value10,​ value11,​value18,​value19,​value20,​ country_id,​ playername_modtime,​player_flag from playername WHERE 'true' != 'false' OR playername.playername_modtime > '2014-05-23 10:38:56' Processing Document # 1 Last Check: 5/23/2014 8:36:34 PM`

Comment: Surely there is something more to the error message you get than "indexing failed".  Please edit your question to show the full and exact error message, cut & pasted from the logs, rather than a paraphrase.

Comment: Hi Andy Thanks for the reply the error i get in the log is "Unable to execute query".But i dont understand how is the query running fine for lesser number of records but fails when i run more number of records

Comment: This exception is CommunicationsException and due to the link failure. Is your mysql in different machine or in the same machine?

Comment: Hi prem Thanks for the reply,Every thing is on the same machine.Running on localhost.But if its a link failure why is the link failing for large number of data only but runs fine for lesser number of data.Plz help,its been 5 days and iam just not able to figure out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added batchSize="-1" to data-config.xml and it worked

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerFaq